# Align inputs vertically

Tags: html, css

I have an `input` inside a `h3` tag, both are inside of a `li` list.
I'd like to know how may I justify/align vertically the inputs so no matter the size of the `h3` text it will be in the same 'column' (every input will be in the same vertical line).  Real Example [Here](http://codepen.io/Ghaleon/pen/zGQMpw)
Even if I edit input's width, it will not be in the same 'column'. Tried to work with `width: calc(..)` but I really don't know how to do it.

```
<ul class="prof-list col-md-4">             
       <li data-id=" 1">
          <h3 class="prof-name">Alan Naidon
             <input type="checkbox" name="" class="check_prof" value="">
          </h3>

          <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable" style="display: none;">
             <li data-id="3" class="ui-sortable-handle">Ingles</li>
          </ul>
       </li>

       <li data-id=" 2">
          <h3 class="prof-name">Antonio Nunnes
             <input type="checkbox" name="" class="check_prof" value="">        
          </h3>
          <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable" style="display: none;">
            <li data-id="5" class="ui-sortable-handle">Lab II</li>
          </ul>
       </li>                
       <li data-id=" 3">
          <h3 class="prof-name">Carlos Cardoso
             <input type="checkbox" name="" class="check_prof" value="">        
          </h3>
          <ul class="list-disc ui-sortable">
             <li data-id="6" class="ui-sortable-handle">Lab I</li>
          </ul>
       </li>
```

Comment: Question is - where checkboxes should be positioned? More ways to do it... one is here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXRmvg

Comment: @nevermind Thanks dude ! I was trying not to use `position: absolute` but your example worked nice.

Comment: No problem, position:absolute is not so bad, imho... Sometimes, shortest and easiest way to make things work... :)

Answer (score 0):

You could give all h3 tags the same width, then give all the inputs the same margin-right value

Answer (score 0):

You can move the inputs outside of the h3 tag and put float:right on them (and ensure that the li tags are all the same width)